# How to pick up how to get elements from List in Scala?

Tags: scala, list

I have a list of elements `List(1,2,3,4,5,6)` which I hope to get a few elements from it to form a new `List` to `List(2,4,5,6)`.

How should I go about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scala collections can be mapped or filtered. In your case you simply can filter with the function you want.

eg. in scala REPL.

filter elements which are greater than or equals to 2.

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6).filter(_>=2)
res3: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

or to filter all elements **which are not 1 and 3,**

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6).filter(element => (element!=1 && element!=3))
res6: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 5, 6)
```

### Also read

https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html#filter

http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-filter-method-scala-collections-cookbook